# Pipenv with git repos not working correctly

Tags: python, git, pipenv

I'm currently experiencing the following issues:

When it is being run from docker-compose, Django fails to migrate due to inexistent migration which [comes from a package installed from Github](https://github.com/math-a3k/tradero/blob/dev/Pipfile#L46)

```
django-ai = {ref = "tradero", git = "https://github.com/math-a3k/django-ai.git"}
```

When it succeeds in installing, I get the following error when migrating:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration base.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('supervised_learning', '0013_alter_oneclasssvc_nu')
```

When checking the repo, [that file exists in it](https://github.com/math-a3k/django-ai/tree/tradero/django_ai/supervised_learning/migrations), and when I inspect the container, I find the directory is empty:

```
(tradero) [bot@femputadora tradero]$ docker exec -it tradero-instance-1 /bin/bash       
root@instance:/home/tradero# ls .venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django_ai/supervised_learning/migrations/
__init__.py  __pycache__
root@instance:/home/tradero# ls .venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django_ai/ai_base/migrations/
0001_initial.py  0002_learningtechnique_cift_is_enabled.py  0003_engineobjectmodel_default_metadata.py  0004_alter_learningtechnique_id.py  0005_alter_learningtechnique_learning_fields.py  __init__.py  __pycache__
```

I tried cleaning all the Docker cache, rebuilding, etc. without success, and any clue about what may be the problem or how to fix it.

[This error was previously spotted on Github's CI](https://github.com/math-a3k/tradero/actions/workflows/code-compliance.yml), I thought it was due to outdated dependencies or because of random timeout errors you may get when installing with Pipenv, [because the commit when the action begins to fail does not introduces any relevant changes from my POV](https://github.com/math-a3k/tradero/commit/96f04854309132c650c7126cd99578a0a8c8a1a6), but the error is reproduced locally with Docker now, and I can't find any reason for that directory to be empty.

There seems to be a problem with the cloning from Pipenv, regular repo cloning shows all the files, and local development without Docker also works, any idea of what may be happening is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Update (2023-09-04):

- It is not related to Docker, as the problem began to shows in non-dockerized envs
- It seems not related to Github itself, as it works with pip
- I found a [temporary workaround](https://github.com/math-a3k/tradero/commit/2cc208a0a4a6cbc1e8757c257632dc86eabb0740) by installing the package with pip and downgrading Pipenv